# How to set a child component without rendering it in the parent component?

Tags: reactjs, reactive-programming

My parent component retrieves a list and inflates it as a table.
I want the row click cb (`onRowClick`) to populate another component with some data from the parent component props/state.
I know this can be done using redux.  Is there another way to simply set a child component without rendering it and then set its props on the click cb?

The click cb is currently looking like this:

```
onRowClick={(event) => {
    return <ChildComponent data={props.data.data[event.index]} />
  }}
```

This doesn't call the `ChildComponent` `render` function since the components aren't connected.

Comment: is `ChildComponent` meant to be rendered inside the `RowComponent`?

Comment: Nope, in another place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  you dont want to use redux, you can use simple props to pass a function that sets state, and pass the state data to the other component.

```
const App = () => {
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch api here
    setApiData();
  })
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  return (
    <>
    <Component1 tableData={apiData} onRowClick={setdata} />
    <ChildComponent data={data}/>
    </>
  );
}
```

If the two components are far apart in the tree, then you can use react contexts to pass data between them.